# Getting text height to know fill height as in TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I'm trying to go through the code of [TCPDF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/) to understand how it calculates the height of the text to be rendered, but it's too much for me to handle without asking.

What I want to know: in the PDF from example 5 http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_005.pdf it gives the cell a yellow background. I'm guessing that at the basic level, it first draws a box with this fill color, then adds the text, so what method is it calling to get the height of the text to know the height of the box to fill?

I can see from the example code that `MultiCell()` is the entry point, but it's not clear what's the method it calls to get the height of the text. I pasted the code for `MultiCell()` in this pastebin

http://pastebin.com/A1niGrQG

Anyone knows how to trace this, because doing it by hand and looking through the code isn't working at all for me.

Comment: Did you review the code for that specific example page?   http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_005.phps

Comment: @CarpeNoctumDC The example code shows that MultiCell is the entry point, but when you look at MultiCell, it's not clear how the text height is being calculated. I may paste the code up there.

Comment: Do you mean the font size?     That is also defined....

Comment: Added a second answer as a starting point/proof of concept..  Although it requies a set font-size, line-height, and the use of a monospaced font w/ known width..    But if you are designing with one font and one size it will work...+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cell is being drawn by MultiCell:
http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_005.phps

```
$pdf->MultiCell(55, 5, '[LEFT] '.$txt, 1, 'L', 1, 0, '', '', true);
```

and from: http://api.joomla.org/com-tecnick-tcpdf/TCPDF.html

```
 int MultiCell (float $w, float $h, string $txt, [mixed $border = 0], [string $align = 'J'], [int $fill = 0], [int $ln = 1], [int $x = ''], [int $y = ''], [boolean $reseth = true], [int $stretch = 0])
```

So as you can see, the first two values are statically assigning a width (55) and a height (5) to the MultiCell

---

Additionally:

```
// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

You can see the unit of measurement is the program/class default PDF_UNIT

---

The font size is then set with

```
$pdf->SetFont('times', '', 10);
```

(or just use SetFontSize  for the size only)

Comment: See my comment above, looks like we posted at the same time. The thing is I doubt that assigning height manually is the main way, because you can give any text a background, so it must be that the library has a method to calculate text height for any text without depending on manual input of height. +1 nonetheless for the attempt.

Comment: I pasted the code for MultiCell() into this pastebin http://pastebin.com/A1niGrQG Are you familiar with TCPDF?

Comment: Pulling up the code now...    So that is just the method for multiCell ?  RIght?

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to get the text size to fill the cell?       Really: you dont..   You set your text size to whatever you want it to be (in points)...  Then you set your multicell to whatever you want it to be  (in PDF_UNIT or whatever scale you used for the document)...  Then you input your text..      In the example i believ they had their multicell demensions smaller than the amount of text - so the cell automaticallyi enlarged to encompase the text...   (multicell size is a minumum size - i.e. in case the content was smaller than the cell..)

Comment: No, I'm not trying to figure out how to get the text size to fill the cell. I'm just using this as an example to get to the code I want. I'm working on a different use case, which basically requires me to find out the height of the text. If width is 300 and I have 2 paragraphs (factor in the font type), what's the height of this text? Somewhere in this lib code, it knows how to calculate that height. If you look at comments of MultiCell() is says $h is minimum height, but it expands automatically as needed. So I think the code is more intelligent than needing the height fed to it manually.

Comment: Ahh okay $text_height = $this->getStringHeight($w, $txt, $reseth, $autopadding, $mc_padding, $border);  Is the line you need to investigate...  Lemme pull up the class and find that method

Comment: Okay..  Well  the direct answer to your qeuestoin now becomes rather in depth and complex...  SHort version?  You take the string, calculate the needed witdth of the characters in the string, then divide that by the specified width to get your number of lines, then you multiply the number of lines by the string/line height.. to get your final height

Comment: Big question is are you using web-safe fonts for this or ? i.e. where is the output of this going to appear?  The main reason i ask is one of the core components to the TCPDF is the font library..   SO depending upon how and where your looking to apply this you may be needing a lions share of the existing coe..

Comment: @CarpeNoctumDC, Thanks, what I was looking for. I'm outputting to PDF still and I'm using the default fonts that come with tcpdf, so not importing new fonts. Do you see any problems?

Comment: Oh well if thats the case then yeah.. You can just call the same functions/methods to get the line heights...  So really there shouldnt be any problems at all...

Answer (score 6):

**TCPDF** (at least the latest version) includes the method `getStringHeight()` which get the estimated height needed for printing a simple text string using the `Multicell()` method.
Additionally, the `getNumLines()` method gives you the estimatad number of lines.
Check the source code documentation at http://www.tcpdf.org for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a very simple proof of concept for what i said in my last comment on my other answer...

** You need to use a **monospaced** font and a line height equal to your text height (that or modify the code for line height instead of text height)  fairly simple fix...

You also have to figure out your aproximate monospaced width..  Best thing to do is use a capitol M (M is the widest char - so monospaced chars are set to this width..)

```
<html><head></head><body style="font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace; line-height:12px;">
<?php

//If you are using a monospace font, this kinda works
$divWidth = 300;  // in px;

$fontSize = 12;  // (in px);
$fontWidth = 7;  // in px - aprox monospace font width


$lineChars = floor($divWidth / $fontWidth);


$text = <<<EOT
MMMMMMMMMM (capital M is the widest character)I'm trying to go through the code of TCPDF to understand how it calculates the height of the text to be rendered, but it's too much for me to handle without asking. 

What I want to know: in the PDF from example 5 it gives the cell a yellow background. I'm guessing that at the basic level, it first draws a box with this fill color, then adds the text, so what method is it calling to get the height of the text to know the height of the box to fill? 

I can see from the example code that MultiCell() is the entry point, but it's not clear what's the method it calls to get the height of the text. I pasted the code for MultiCell() in this pastebin 
EOT;


$wrappedText = wordwrap($text, $lineChars, "LINEHERE");
$lines = substr_count($wrappedText, "LINEHERE");
$newlines = substr_count($text, "\n");
$text = str_replace("\n", "<br>",$text);
$lines += $newlines;

$divHeight = $lines * $fontSize;
echo "With a width of: " . $divWidth . "<br>";
echo "Number of Lines: " . $lines . "<br>";
echo "Height Required: " . $divHeight . "px<br>";
echo "Wrapped Text at: " . $lineChars . " characters<br><br>";

$divsize = "width:$divWidth px; height:$divHeight px; font-size:$fontSize px; ";

$outStr = "<div style='overflow:auto; display:inline-block; background-color:aqua; $divsize'>$text</div>";
$outStr .= "<div style=' display:inline-block; background-color:fuchsia; $divsize'>&nbsp;</div>";

echo $outStr;
?> 
</body></html>
```